# WRONG: showing data in two different places php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have 2 sections in my web page: 
[image]

im trying to show different data from my database:

```
<?php
$id=$_GET['vari'];
include 'conexion.php';
$con=conexion();
$sql="select * from cliente where idcli='".$id."'";
$res=mysql_query($sql,$con);
$fila=mysql_fetch_array($res);
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

and

```
<?php



$idusu =   $_SESSION['idusuario']; 
    $sqlcot="select c.idcotiza, c.fechacotiza, c.proyecto, u.nomusuario, c.status from cotizacion c, usuario u where c.idusuario = u.idusuario and c.idcli= ".$idusu."'";
    $rescot=mysql_query($sqlcot,$cone);
if($sqlcot === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
    echo mysql_error();
}

//meter en tabla
echo "<html><tr><td>Folio</td><td>Fecha</td><td>Proyecto</td><td>Vendedor</td><td>Status</td></tr>";
while ($dato=mysql_fetch_array($rescot))
{ 
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$dato['c.idcotiza']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$dato['c.fechacotiza']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$dato['c.proyecto']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$dato['u.nomusuario']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$dato['c.status']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";   
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

the first code works! but the second doesnt work...

The message it shows me is:

```
`Notice: Undefined variable: cone in C:\xampp\htdocs\...php on line 378 //but cone is defined

Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\....php on line 378
FolioFechaProyectoVendedorStatus
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\P...l.php on line 386`
```

the php code is in two diferent places in my page

any idea?

Comment: you're going to need to show the code surrounding those errors and include where and how your variables are defined.  `cone` may not be defined for the current scope.  and you should check out `pdo` or `mysqli`.

Comment: for the query... `$con` is null.  you are not connected to the db.  so it errors.  the fetch errors because the result set is invalid bc the query never ran.

Comment: don't close your connection to the DB until after the second part, and change cone to con

Answer (score 1):

All your problems are started from this line

```
$rescot=mysql_query($sqlcot,$cone);
```

make sure $cone variable is defined.

Comment: i bet OP actually means `$con` instead of `$cone`

Comment: which takes it back to the query errors... and the connection is invalid for whatever reason.

Comment: if i add `include 'conexion.php';
 $cone=conexion();` it says `Cannot redeclare conexion() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\..\conexion.php:16) in C:\xampp\htdocs\¨...\conexion.php on line 31`

Comment: can you also provide us also the content from the conexion.php

Answer (score 1):

### Check the $cone

The error says that `$cone` is not defined. Try adding `print_r($cone); die();` right before `mysql_query`.

### Possible Causes to $cone being undefined.

1. The connection resource `$cone` is being unset previously in your code.
2. You may be encountering a namespace issue, try `echo __NAMESPACE__;` to verify.
3. Double check the process to ensure the variable is named the same, and is being set to a connection object.

   - In your previous sample, you set the variable to `$con` not `$cone`.

### Injection Vulnerable

The following section of code would be *highly* vulnerable to sql injection.

```
$id=$_GET['vari'];

$sql="select * from cliente where idcli='".$id."'";
```

Note what would happen if someone put a single-quote in the querystring: `?vari=1'; DROP TABLE cliente where '1'='1`

### PHP PDO

Please consider using [PHP:PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php).

Comment: Using `bindParam` PHP:PDO for this kind of SQL operation is currently the **best** way to ensure your code is not injection vulnerable, while also removing the necessity of keeping track of your apostrophes.